# jQuery moving a table row - Pretty effect

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a simple suggestion voting system where users can +1 or -1 suggestions (in a similar way to how stack-overflow rates questions).

These suggestions are presented in a long table and the +1 or -1 is done through ajax, as the table is sorted by the amount of votes an item has, when one is +1 or -1'd the table loses it's order.

I am aware I can use the table sorter jQuery plugin to fix this but it makes it very easy to lose the item you +-'d, do you know how to move the row up/down the table while following it? (Perhaps similar to the way ordering is done on the iPhone?) with a slick animation?

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to solve this using a few library's and made it look pretty good. What is in fact happening is a duplicate table is being made in the background, then an animation is applied and the two tables are swapped.

See http://jsfiddle.net/NP4t3/1/ and vote people up or down!

It was based on work from http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/01/animating-html-ranking-tables-with-javascript/ and then I added automatic sorting!

All the code is in the fiddle (including the library's), hope this is of use to someone!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any plugin that would do this. However you can write one yourself. I would take the following approach:

- Create a table which has identifiable rows.
- Create a second hidden table inside an absolute positioned div.
- When you want to move a row, detach it from the main table (maybe you want to keep a copy or a empty row as a place holder) and add it to the second table which you can show now and fly it to the desired destination and add it back from the temporary table to the main one.

Oh and there's this question on stackoverflow: [Making a table row animate upward movement in sortable UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997238/making-a-table-row-animate-upward-movement-in-sortable-ui)

I think that should get you started

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is after a very simple solution to this one, you can use jQuery animate() to provide some visual notification to the row after it has moved. For example, fade it in and out.

Here's an example that fades the row out quickly and then back in more slowly:

```
$(row).animate({ opacity: 0.2 }, 170, function () {
    $(row).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 340);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hsxaemf9/16/